# Проблема с линковщиком

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Здравствуйте, пользуюсь `VS C++ 2010`, все нормально, но после установки `MSVS 2012`, при создании консольного проекта возникают проблемы с компиляцией. Ошибка:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt

Поискал в интернете, нашел устранение проблемы: `Project->Propeties->Configuration properties->Linker->General->Enable Incremental Linking: NO`. (по умолчанию там стоит YES). Объясните пожалуйста, что значит, инкрементная линковка? Как устранить эту проблему раз и на всегда? :o

Answer (score 2):

При инкрементальной линковке, линковщик с компилятором не пересобирают все файлы, а только измененные, тем самым минимизируя время сборки проекта.
Видимо, установив две среды, вы получили двойной набор компиляторов+линковщиков. И они имеют немного разный формат. И, к примеру, среда 2012 использует компилятор 2010 и линковщик 2012. И будут проблемы.

На Вашем этапе это решить можно только установив что то одно. Либо садиться и разбираться с переменными среды, с тем, как работает вся эта кухня.

Comment: В вашем ответе сложно с первого раза правильно прочитать слово "кухня" :)

Comment: Откуда, кстати говоря, информация про версии линкера и `C++` компилера в VS2012?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, я думал мне одному то слово привиделось :-)

Comment: конечно, после лурка и двача сложно читать нормальный текст.

Прочитайте эту статью - http://blog.not-a-kernel-guy.com/2012/05/04/1317 там хорошо видно, как оригинально работает VS и почему могут быть интересные баги.

У меня подобное было, когда один хороший человек установил одновременно С++ билдер и vs 6 (это было ещё в году 2002-2003). Но устанавливал он их параллельно (он считал, что это ускорит процесс). А потом ещё PATH отредактировал.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, и правда, хаха =)))